# How can physically disabled people who aren't flying first or business class use the lavatory on a Lufthansa A340-600?

Tags: aircraft, lufthansa, accessibility, toilets

Lufthansa uses the Airbus A340-600 on a large portion of its long-haul routes. According to the [seatmaps](https://www.lufthansa.com/us/en/346) for the two different configurations it uses, all of the lavatories for premium economy and economy are accessed via a staircase into the lower deck (underbelly) of the aircraft, in both configurations. The only toilets on the main deck are located either in front of the plane in first class, or smack in the middle of business class.

This presents a problem for physically disabled passengers (specifically those unable to climb stairs) who aren't flying first or business class.

How does Lufthansa accommodate such passengers, when they want to use the lavatory? Are they offered access to the premium cabins' toilets? Or do they have no choice other than to go down the stairs?

Ideally, I'd prefer an answer from someone who's either flown on this plane as a passenger and has first-hand experience of this issue, or is familiar with the internal Lufthansa policies that govern this.

Comment: You might get a quicker authoritative answer by contacting Lufthansa directly...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a passenger is unable to access the downstairs lavatories due to disabilities then they will be allow to use those located in the business class cabin - in particular the accessible lavatory located around row 10.

As passengers are normally required to use the lavatories in their ticket cabins it would be worth raising this with the fight attendants, either during boarding or during the flight, so that they will not block access when required.

Comment: What's the source on this?

Comment: Based purely on common sense and the general legal requirements that airlines must reasonably accommodate disabled passengers, I can't imagine how else it could possibly be.  But I agree it would be nice to have confirmation.

Comment: @gparyani: If you look at https://www.lufthansa.com/is/en/passengers-using-wheelchairs, there is a note that all long-haul aircraft are equipped with accessible toilets, which in this case must clearly be the one on the main deck, and it would seem to go without saying that a person with disabilities would be allowed to use the accessible toilet.

Comment: @gparyani I don't have a referenceable source, however this is standard practice across basically ALL airlines.  Most (long-haul) planes have one accessible toilet, which is generally located in the business cabin (or at worst, right behind it).  It is standard practice to allow access to it for any disabled passengers in any cabin.